# Is it true that if the associated homegeneous system has a unique solution, then the system also has a unique solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Given a system of linear equations, is it true that if the associated homogeneous system has unique solution (the trivial one), then the system itself has a unique solution?

If this is true, it would mean that there is a mistake in the table from this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/General_%3D_Particular_%2B_Homogeneous) (which seems to be extracted from Jim Hefferson's Linear Algebra book), so I think this is not true, but how to find a counter-example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Consider, for example, the following set of equations
$$x+y=2,\tag 1$$
$$x-y=0, \tag {2}$$
and 
$$x+2y = 2. \tag 3$$

Obviously, the homogeneous solution is unique, i.e. $x=y=0$. But the solution of the linear system does not exist.